# Dynamic attaching property to constructor and use in new object instance?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
var Person = function(firstname, lastname){
  this.firstname = firstname;
  this.lastname = lastname;
};

Person.greet = function(){
  console.log("Hello there ! "+ "My name is: "+ this.firstname);
};

var nk = new Person('Mark', 'Z');
console.log(nk.firstname);

nk.greet(); // Error in attaching
```

So I am trying to attach the function "greet" to the constructor "Person" outside of it. I can certainly do it with prototype but just trying to understand why the above code doesn't work?

For example: this will work:

```
var Person = function(firstname, lastname){
      this.firstname = firstname;
      this.lastname = lastname;
      this.greet = function(){
      console.log("Hello there ! "+ "My name is: "+ this.firstname);
    };
    };

    var nk = new Person('Mark', 'Z');
    console.log(nk.firstname);

    nk.greet();
```

From MDN:

> Function objects created with the Function constructor are parsed when
>   the function is created. This is less efficient than declaring a
>   function with a function expression or function statement and calling
>   it within your code, because such functions are parsed with the rest
>   of the code.
>
> All arguments passed to the function are treated as the names of the
>   identifiers of the parameters in the function to be created, in the
>   order in which they are passed.
>
> Invoking the Function constructor as a function (without using the new
>   operator) has the same effect as invoking it as a constructor.
>
> The global Function object has no methods or properties of its own,
>   however, since it is a function itself it does inherit some methods
>   and properties through the prototype chain from Function.prototype.
>
> Function instances Function instances inherit methods and properties
>   from Function.prototype. As with all constructors, you can change the
>   constructor's prototype object to make changes to all Function
>   instances.

Comment: `Person.prototype.greet = function...` puts the function on the object from which the new instances inherit. `Person` is just a function that facilitates creating objects that inherit from its `.prototype`. It's not involved in the inheritance beyond that.

Comment: Yes Certainly thats the way to do it. But if someone can explain what is going on in the above code, It will be helpful. e.g. I could have added the function "greet" inside the constructor and it would have worked. But if I attach it outside, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know the answer - use the function's prototype object which is specifically intended for creating new instances of your constructor. Consider what you are actually doing:

```
function foo () {
  this.prop = 1
}

foo.bar = function () {
  return this.prop // - not defined
}

foo.prototype.baz = function () {
  return this.prop  // 1
}

var f = new foo()
f.bar // undefined; f.bar() // => Error 
foo.bar // a function that returns undefined when called
f.baz // a function that returns 1 when called
foo.baz // undefined; foo.baz() // => Error
```

The salient point is: The instance =/= the constructor =/= the prototype object. You are defining a property directly on the constructor, this means you can call that property from the constructor `Person.greet()` (even though anything you define on the object in the constructor will be undefined because the constructor function is never called in this case). You cannot call that method from an instance of the function because the instance is a separate object from the constructor function. Defining `this.greet` in the constructor will work, and some people use this approach, however, the one drawback is that these properties will be locked on individual instances. Using the prototype allows you to make a change that affects every instance.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by squint

`Person.prototype.greet = function...` puts the function on the object from which the new instances inherit

That means there will only be one greet function that is shared by all instances.

When you set  `this.greet` in the constructor, you are creating a new instance of the greet function for every instance of person (`new Person().greet != new Person().greet`). It mostly has the same behaviour with a little more memory usage.

When you do `Person.greet`, that attaches a method to the constructor, that is not used for each instance. In classical programming, it could be seen as a static method.

I think you will find my blog post helpful http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2014/10/understanding-prototypical-inheritance.html

Answer (score 1):

The trick is: "this" is not Person constructor, but is the new instance (nk) in your example.

So "this.greet" and"person.greet" are completely different.

In your first example, you attach person.greet, but invoke nk.greet. Thats the reason.